# Well-founded or wellfounded?

Tags: style

Both of the the terms are used in some mathematical literature, especially on set theory. Is one of them preferable to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well-founded in normal English. (meaning based on good reasoning)

Either in the technical set theory sense. See the opening paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation

Comment: One also encounters "well founded" in much set theory literature.

May ill-founded serve as an appropriate antonym?

Comment: The term usually adopted for what I have in mind for ill-founded is non-wellfounded.

Comment: I don't understand the question, as you already have the answer!  If the normal term is "non-wellfounded" then use the normal term.